# How can I get OkCupid search to show only matches within 5 miles of me?

Tags: search, okcupid

Researchers have found that friendships are more likely to last if both friends live near each other.<sup>[*[citation needed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citation_needed)*]</sup>

I'm using [OkCupid](http://www.okcupid.com/), a free online-dating and friend-matching site. When I search for matches, OkCupid lets me filter the list of potential matches by proximity. But the closest proximity option is "within 25 miles of me". How can I search for matches who live within 5 miles of me?

**NOTE:** For non-US users, OkCupid's 5-mile and 10-mile proximity filters [usually don't work as expected](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60101/why-is-okcupid-showing-me-matches-who-live-more-than-5-kilometers-away). Outside the US, these filters can't narrow down search results within cities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OkCupid have kindly [finally made this easy to achieve](http://www.reddit.com/r/OkCupid/comments/1lt40h/5_and_10_mikm_radius_options_now_available/).

1. Visit http://www.okcupid.com/match.
2. Click on the drop-down list which lets you choose your search radius.
3. Choose "5 miles".
4. Click the big blue "Search" button.

If you want an even finer-grained search, tell OkCupid to [show only matches within 5 kilometers](http://www.reddit.com/r/OkCupid/comments/1lt40h/5_and_10_mikm_radius_options_now_available/cc2i20v). Kilometers are smaller than miles; 5 kilometers equal approximately 3.1 miles.

**NOTE:** For non-US users, OkCupid's 5-mile and 10-mile proximity filters [usually don't work as expected](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60101/why-is-okcupid-showing-me-matches-who-live-more-than-5-kilometers-away). Outside the US, these filters can't narrow down search results within cities.

Comment: OkCupid seems to have taken away the search function as of 2020.